# Problems with Visual Studio 2008, Windows 7, GAC

Tags: visual-studio-2008, windows-7, 64-bit, x86-64

The issue has been giving me nightmares since Monday.
Everything was going fine till i received my new Windows 7 64-bit PC.
Since our application is basically run on 32-bit machines. I recompiled all my projects as **x86** (earlier this was configured as Any CPU in my old 32-bit machine).

Also we have many strong named assemblies in our application, the newly compiled dlls were installed in the GAC. So far so good. All my projects compiled successfully.

The problem started when i ran my application. The Visual Studio 2008 was not able to load 
the strong named assemblies which were in the GAC. It flashed me a message saying that the assembly referred in my project does not conform to the one present in the GAC. I checked everything, both the assemblies have the same public key and the version number.

And when i google about using dlls in the GAC in the 64bit machines, i come across **GAC_32 and GAC_UTIL** directory structures which has led me into more confusion. All i know now is that i have a super fast machine i cannot run my application on it.

**

```
OS Name Microsoft Windows 7 Professional
Version 6.1.7600 Build 7600
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     E8400  @ 3.00GHz, 3000 Mhz, 2 Core(s), 2 Logical Processor(s)
```

**

Please help !!

Comment: Forgot to add , my application runs when i configure my application as "Any CPU"

Comment: Given that piece of information, my first guess would be that your assemblies in the GAC are compiled for 64-bit machines. That's why your project doesn't run correctly when you compile for x86, but it *does* run correctly compiled for "Any CPU" because you're on a 64-bit machine, where it will run as x64.

Comment: I see my assemblies only in the GAC_32 directory. There are no assemblies for 64-bit in the GAC (i.e in the GAC_64 directory). I can safely conclude the ones present in the GAC are assemblies(x86) and not x64.